# Trigger.IO Serve iOS request not working

Tags: ios, ajax, request, trigger.io

I'm trying to use "Serve" feature (since every build requires uploading whole app now) but once the install is finished i get below error the app got stuck:

> Webview error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request
>   timed out." UserInfo=0x14e6fca0
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=`http://192.168.56.1:31337/src/index.html`,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=`http://192.168.56.1:31337/src/index.html`,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x14e3b920 "The request timed out."}

From what i can tell this indicates that the first ajax request the app makes fails with "The request timed out" message. Why is this happening? This doesn't happen when i build normally just with Serve option. My platform version is 2.2.5 (most recent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common cause for this is if the mobile device you are testing on isn't on the same network as your development machine.

A quick way to check this is to look at the network settings of the device and make sure it has an IP in the same range as your machine. (i.e. 192.168.56.x)

Another possibility is that your development machine is running a local firewall or other software that could be blocking incoming network requests from your device.

Comment: it appears i had a VM virtualbox which created a virtual network and device was trying to connect that one instead.